Session is null when making a POST request from Chrome extension to Next.js API
I'm working on a Next.js application with NextAuth for authentication, and I'm trying to handle a POST request to manage user tokens. However, I'm consistently receiving null for the session when I make the request from my Chrome extension.
Here's my API route implementation for handling the token management:
// src/app/api/user/tokens/route.js

import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "@/app/libs/next-auth";

// Handler for POST requests
export async function POST(req) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  console.log(session);
  if (!session) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "Unauthorized" }), {
      status: 401,
    });
  }

  // Process your POST request here
  const data = await req.json(); // For example, read the request body

  // Your logic to handle tokens goes here

  return new Response(
    JSON.stringify({ message: "Success", user: session.user }),
    { status: 200 }
  );
}

// Example for a GET request:
export async function GET(req) {
  return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "GET request successful" }), {
    status: 200,
  });
}

Chrome Extension Code
Here's the function in my Chrome extension that makes the POST request:
async function decreaseUserTokens() {
  try {
    // Check authentication and get user info
    const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "checkAuth" });

    if (response && response.user) {
      // Make a POST request to decrease tokens
      const updateResponse = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/user/tokens",
        {
          method: "POST",
          credentials: "include",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );

      if (!updateResponse.ok) {
        console.error(`Failed to update tokens: ${updateResponse.statusText}`);
        return false;
      }

      const data = await updateResponse.json();
      console.log("Tokens updated successfully:", data);
      return data.tokens;
    }

    console.error("User is not authenticated");
    return 0;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating tokens:", error);
    return 0;
  }
}

NextAuth Configuration
My NextAuth configuration looks like this:
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";
import connectMongo from "../libs/mongo";

export const authOptions = {
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
      profile(profile, tokens) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.given_name ? profile.given_name : profile.name,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.picture,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          tokens: 0, // Set initial tokens
          plan: "free", // Set initial plan
        };
      },
    }),
    ...(connectMongo
      ? [
          EmailProvider({
            server: {
              host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
              port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
              auth: {
                user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
                pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
              },
            },
            from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
          }),
        ]
      : []),
  ],
  ...(connectMongo && { adapter: MongoDBAdapter(connectMongo) }),
  pages: {
    signIn: "/sign-in", // Your custom sign in page
    verifyRequest: "/auth/verify-request", // Your custom verify request page
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.tokens = user.tokens;
        token.plan = user.plan;
      }
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return {
        ...token,
        accessToken: token.jti, // Include the JWT token ID
      };
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.id = token.id;
      session.user.tokens = token.tokens;
      session.user.plan = token.plan;
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken; // Add JWT token to session
      return session;
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
};

Problem
No matter what I try, the session is always null when I send the POST request from my Chrome extension. Here are a few things I have checked:
The session cookie is being set in the browser.
CORS is not an issue since I'm testing on localhost.
The user is authenticated before making the request.
Question
What could be causing the session to be null in my Next.js API route when making a POST request from my Chrome extension? Are there any specific steps or configurations I should check to resolve this issue?
